# See SOAP format into web services with fiddler

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, fiddler

I create a web services and a ConsoleApplication to consume it. I am using fiddler to see the traffic, i was hoping that the request and response was SOAP but that's don't happend, only the request was SOAP, not the response.
How can i force to my service that respond using soap?

This is the raw http header obtained:
*HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Cache-Control: private, max-age=0

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

Content-Encoding: gzip

Vary: Accept-Encoding

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Date: Mon, 17 Nov 2014 20:19:22 GMT

Content-Length: 311*

The respond is in binary.
My web-service was created adding a Web Services item to ASP.NET Empty Web Application project, and i don't modified, later I published in IIS.
My consumer is very simple too. I just add the service reference and create an instance.

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://172.20.48.59/web-services/MyWebService.asmx");
var serviceRefWithoutConfig = new ServiceReference1.MyWebServiceSoapClient(binding, endpointAddress);
Console.WriteLine(serviceRefWithoutConfig.HelloWorld());
```

Comment: What format was the response?

Comment: but my consumer application show me the correct answer

Comment: Is Fiddler not hiding the SOAP? What does, for instance, WireShark show as the response?

Comment: I think not, becuase i have been used the web services from a camera and it show the soap.

Comment: what you mean with WireShark?

Comment: WireShark is a (low level) network traffic sniffer. Very useful for these kind of debugging: https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Oh! I don't have any sniffer, would you know some link to download?

Comment: It is a free tool and can be obtained from the Wireshark website: https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: Thank, however the service must respond a Soap message, it true that?

Comment: Yes, it should do that. Might be some attribute might fed it up. Therefore, if you post the response that you get, it might reveal what is happening under the hood.

Comment: How can we know what the problem is with your service if you don't show us the code?

Comment: i show you the code now

Comment: Did you write the service? Then show us the (basic) code from the _service_. It's the _service_ that decides how the _service_ responds.

Comment: And, how do you know it's not returning SOAP? Are you expecting your Console.WriteLine to output XML? That's not how it works.

Comment: it's not returning a SOAP, i'll see the http response with fidler and it's not. I don't use Console.WriteLine to output XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP response in question is compressed with GZIP.

What happens after you click the big yellow bar in Fiddler that says `Response is encoded and may require decoding before inspection. Click here to transform.`?

Comment: how do you handle this in the code? how can I make the client decompress it?

Comment: There's not nearly enough information in your question to answer it. Every platform and language behaves differently, but almost all HTTP stacks have a flag that allow them to decompress HTTP compressed responses. Instead of asking questions in comments, search for relevant questions at the top level, and in the unlikely event you cannot find the answer, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating something new, I strongly suggest you look at using WebAPI for something like this.

It's much easier to control the output of your methods, and the resulting service will be easier to consume from mobile platforms, should the need arise in future.